# Execute checks before initialization list

Tags: c++, class, constructor, member-initialization

I have a member of class A in my own class which constructor takes multiple parameters. Im forwarding parameters of my own class to the constructor of class A. But its important that these parameters are correct, so i need to check them before consructing the member of A. And heres the problem:
I could leave out the member in the member intialization list, effectively calling the default constructor. After the checks in the constructor i could then call A`s constructor in a assigment. Although, this produces a error since the destructor of A is private.

How do i solve this?

```
MyClass::MyClass(int someParam) : otherMember(2){
//checks for someParam
member = A(someParam); // <- produces error
}
```

Comment: Talk to the author of class `A` and coerce her to make `A`'s own constructor behave sensibly in the event of illegal parameter values.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to construct `A` and then check after the fact?

Comment: I actually tried to persuade Sun to make this acceptable in Java, but they refused. It's slightly easier to cheat in Java because you can call one constructor from another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're going to need an accessible destructor no matter what you do. But to address your question, one option would be to call a static function to check parameters from within the initializer:

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    static void checkParam(int);
// ...
};

MyClass::MyClass(int someParam) : otherMember( (checkParam(someParam), 2) ) {
  // ...
}

static void MyClass::checkParam(int someParam) {
  if (...) throw someException();
}
```

Note that the `,` used there is the comma operator, not an argument separator - it evaluates both left and right expressions, and throws away the result of the left.

Comment: Would exceptions thrown in checkParam() still interrupt programflow? If the answer to this question is yes, this is exactly what i need. For those of you who are wondering about the private destructor, its a reference counted objected; I gueess using the appropiate reference counting pointer would be better.

Comment: Yes. checkParam will be evaluated before `2`, so if it throws, `2` will not evaluate, and thus `otherMember`'s constructor cannot be invoked

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of approaching this:

1. Make sure class `A` can be used with a parameter-less constructor, and set `someParam` in a separate method: `A.SetSomeParam(someParam)`
2. Not inherit from `A`, but rather hold a member object of type `A`, and then you can construct it whenever you like.